# State not update when using axios get React

Tags: ajax, reactjs, axios

i want to make select input with data from API. so i use axios to receive the data from server and save to state. But when i use this.setState, the state not updated. and i can't use it in render method. can you please help me about my problem

```
        import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import AddCFRulesCss from "../css/addclub.module.css";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";

class AddCFRules extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataMusim: [],
      musim: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      axios.get('http://localhost:80/skripsi2/getallseason.php')
      .then(res => {
          const response = res.data;
          this.setState({ dataMusim: response });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container fluid="xs" className={AddCFRulesCss.container}>
        <Form className={AddCFRulesCss.form}>
          <p className={AddCFRulesCss.form__title}>tambah aturan CF</p>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>Pilih Musim</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="select" name="musim" required>
              {this.state.dataMusim.map(musim => {
                return (
                  <option key={musim.id} value={musim.nama}>
                    {musim.nama}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <button type="submit" className={AddCFRulesCss.form__button}>
            tambah aturan CF
          </button>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default AddCFRules;
```

Comment: Is it throwing some error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve i forgot to add () in map

before :

```
 {this.state.dataMusim.map(musim => {
            return (
              <option key={musim.id} value={musim.nama}>
                {musim.nama}
              </option>
            );
          })}
```

after :

```
{this.state.dataMusim.map((musim) => {
            return (
              <option value={musim.musim} key={musim.id}>{musim.musim}</option>
            );
          })}
```